# search result in month using mysql or cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Hi everyone i have one question search result month in using MySql or Cakephp my table name is state_supplies and data are

[image]

MySql query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `state_supplies` WHERE created=DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m')
```

Cakephp search code is

```
$this->StateSupply->find('all', array(
                      'conditions'=> array(
                        'unitid'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.unitid'),
                        'created'=>'MONTH(CURDATE())'
                      )                 
                    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

***In Mysql:***

```
$first_day_this_month = date('Y-m-01 H:i:s'); // hard-coded '01' for first day
$last_day_this_month  = date('Y-m-t H:i:s');
$sql="SELECT * FROM state_supplies WHERE created between '$first_day_this_month' and '$last_day_this_month' "
```

***Cakephp code***

[Details](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions)

**Update code for right answer**

```
 $this->StateSupply->find('all',array(
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'unitid'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.unitid'),
                    'crop'=>$this->request->data['StateSupply']['crop'],
                    'state'=>$this->request->data['StateSupply']['state'],
                    'created BETWEEN ? AND ?'=>array(date('Y-m-01',strtotime('this month')),date('Y-m-t',strtotime('this month')))
                        )                   
                    )
                );
```

Comment: @vikram sharma it works for me. it run by sql code `SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE invoice_date between '2015-01-01 11:31:06' and '2015-01-31 11:31:06' ` and it works in phpmyadmin sql field.

Comment: it's ok you have another query please share it

Comment: Ok, thanks and glad to see accept my answer. And if my answer have any problem, then edit this. i will aprove.